# Compare yymmdd date to today

Tags: mysql, date, compare

In my db I have the dates stored in yymmdd format. Is there a way to compare them to todays date in MYSQL query?

This one obviously doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created >= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best fix: use native mysql date fields instead of your custom varchar format, and the problem goes away.

That being said, at least your format is in "most significant part first" format, so

```
SELECT ...
WHERE created >= DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%y%m%d')
```

should work, with the caveat that you're not y2k compliant.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the created column first like that and then compare it

```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE STR_TO_DATE(created, '%Y-%m-%d') >= CURDATE();
```